# Onclick: open .exe in new window while redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser

I'm trying to build a download button which when clicked, starts the download of a file in a new window while redirecting to a "you are currently downloading" page in the original window. There are a variety of reasons why I need it to work this way instead of redirecting to the download file from the "you are currently downloading" page.

My code works fine in IE, Chrome, and Firefox, but doesn't launch the setup.exe in Safari.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var link = $j('#slider_download_link a')[0];
    link.href = 'setup.exe'; // This link is dependent on the browser and OS. For example, on Mac I'd link to the Mac App Store
    link.target = "_blank";
    link.onclick = RedirectToDownloadingPage;
});

function RedirectToDownloadingPage()
{
    location.href="/downloading";
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the click handler is fired, page navigation begins and Safari apparently stops doing anything else with the current page, including letting your link fire.  So, delay the click handler until after the link has been activated with `setTimeout()`:

```
function RedirectToDownloadingPage()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        location.href="/downloading";
    }, 100);
    return true;
}
```

In my experimentation, a timeout value of `0` was adequate, but it's probably a good idea to increase that slightly, just to be safe.  Something like `100` should be enough.